# Parse isue with REST addon

Tags: templates, parse-order, parsing, parse

Yet another parse order problem!

I'm trying to use http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/rest. This works:

```
{exp:rest url="/api/get-default-profile-image/175/" format="json"}
    {default_profile_image}
{/exp:rest}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
{exp:rest url="/api/get-default-profile-image/{member_id}/" format="json"}
    {default_profile_image}
{/exp:rest}
```

(I changed the `175` with `{member_id}`. Any suggestions how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use [Mo Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) which provides an ***early parsed*** `{logged_in_member_id}` which will allow you to use it as a dynamic value in your URL path.

```
{exp:rest url="/api/get-default-profile-image/{logged_in_member_id}/" format="json" parse="inward"}
    {default_profile_image}
{/exp:rest}
```